# Slow views render time

Tags: views, commerce

I am using Drupal commerce for one of my clients. I notice that the view with orders which are in a checkout status take several seconds to load. After i enable views statistics the numbers are

```
Query build time    23.51 ms
Query execute time  4.33 ms
View render time    209.68 ms
```

Which are pretty fast. But despite of the 200ms it takes 6-7 secs to load the view. What could cause this?? Any directions  in order to debug this??

My server is VPS and well configured. I only have this problem with this actual site.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you checked that it isn't something on the page rather than server performance? Firebug / Chrome developer tools can be used to spot possible issues there. One quick diagnostic is disabling Javascript and reloading the page if possible.

Comment: Do you enabled page caching for anonymous users? And Views caching? Or maybe you [deleted some module without firstly disabling it](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/887/11153)?

Comment: user11153's questions don't apply to the View in question. I'd follow-up on Alfred's suggestions. If it isn't the query and it isn't the rendering, then it must be some other piece of the page.

Comment: The page is the "Seven theme" for admin. I'm pretty sure that there is nothing else loading in there... Pretty confusing stuff...

Comment: I just noticed that when i try to load a view that shows order that are in the cart or in checkout process     hook_commerce_order_presave() is running. Is it normal???

Answer (score 1):

Though view is a powerful module, it can cause a lot of performance problems if certain things are not handled. There a certain steps you can follow to fix this.

There are several things you can do to solve improve this:

**Optimizing View:**

- Try to change `left join` to `inner join` using alter.
- Enable Cache on views and clear it when order is updated.
- Check if Distinct is marked.

**Here is a sample views alter code:**

```
/**
* Implements hook_views_query_alter().
*
* This disables distinct and turns LEFT joins into INNER joins. This increases
* performance.
*/
function my_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
if ($view->name == "my_view") {
$query->table_queue['content_type_article']['join']->type = 'INNER';
$query->distinct = 0;
}
}
```

Optimizing view is a wider topic, there is a [good write up](http://blog.safwan.in/post/69062911105/optimizing-views-queries-in-drupal) on optimizing views that you can read to understand this better [here](http://blog.safwan.in/post/69062911105/optimizing-views-queries-in-drupal).

Other than this you should check if your mysql configuration in my.cnf is optimized as per your system resources. For this you could use [mysqltuner](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/mysqltuner-check-your-mysql-server-performance.html) script or [mysql-tuning-primer](https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer) script.

Above that use of [memcached](https://drupal.org/project/memcache) with Drupal can also increase performance to great extend.